# Nested member type recognition

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Today, I was trying to perform a type switch on whether some class has the nested type `reverse_iterator` or not. I found on these fora some working solution, which is the following one:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_reverse_iterable
{
    using yes   = uint8_t;
    using no    = uint16_t;

    template<typename U>
    static yes& test(typename U::reverse_iterator*);

    template<typename>
    static no& test(...);

    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

This class works just fine if I simply check the condition from the main, however, I also wrote that little function, which cause some problems.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& iter)
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_reverse_iterable<T>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the main that causes me some problems:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<int> v;

    cout << typeid(decltype(v)).name() << endl;
    cout << is_reverse_iterable<decltype(v)>::value << endl;

    foo(v);

    return 0;
}
```

As `std::vector<int>` contains the nested type name `reverse_iterator`, one would think - or at least, I would think - that `is_reverse_iterable<vector<int>>::value` would return true wherever I put it. But it's not the case. Here is the result of the main above:

```
St6vectorIiSaIiEE
1
St6vectorIiSaIiEE
0
```

When called from the main, the struct `is_reverse_iterable` recognized the name `reverse_iterator` in `vector<int>`, but it did not do so when called from `foo`. Actually, I have no idea why, and I would like someone to please explain to me what the problem is :)

P.S. : I use MinGW g++ 4.7.1 to compile, with the option -std=c++11.

Comment: I dont get what you mean by " it seems that the code can't find the nested type reverse_iterator anymore," ... does it not compile? if not, whats the compile error? if yes, what does that sentence mean, since the compiler could find everything it needed to compile...

Comment: I located the problem and tried to explain where it occurs. Sorry for having been unclear before :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `foo(v)`, it is deduced that `T` is of type `std::vector<int>&` (**an lvalue-reference**), so `typename T::reverse_iterator` will not compile. You can easily check it yourself:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& iter)
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_reverse_iterable<T>::value << std::endl;

    typename T::reverse_iterator t;  // <-- add this line to see what's wrong
}
```

Yields:

```
3.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void foo(T&&) [with T = std::vector<int>&]’:
3.cpp:40:10:   required from here
3.cpp:27:34: error: ‘std::vector<int>&’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

The solution is simple: remove the reference before you start the SFINAE, e.g.

```
static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<typename std::decay<T>::type>(0))
                                == sizeof(yes);
```

Comment: Simple and clean answer, thank you very much. I somehow thought of using a `remove_reference` or so somewhere, without being sure, but your answer was even faster. Thanks again! :)